# What are the other NaN values?

Tags: java, floating-point, ieee-754, nan

The [documentation for `java.lang.Double.NaN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) says that it is

> A constant holding a Not-a-Number (NaN) value of type `double`. It is equivalent to the value returned by `Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L)`.

This seems to imply there are others. If so, how do I get hold of them, and can this be done portably?

To be clear, I would like to find the `double` values `x` such that

```
Double.doubleToRawLongBits(x) != Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Double.NaN)
```

and

```
Double.isNaN(x)
```

are both true.

Comment: Do you mean are there other `java.lang.*.NaN`?

Comment: @Dominic: No - I've added what I think is a clarification to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need `doubleToRawLongBits` rather than `doubleToLongBits`.

`doubleToRawLongBits` extracts the actual binary representation.  `doubleToLongBits`  doesn't, it converts all `NaN`s to the default `NaN` first.

```
double n = Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L); // default NaN
double n2 = Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000100L); // also a NaN, but M != 0

System.out.printf("%X\n", Double.doubleToLongBits(n));
System.out.printf("%X\n", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(n));
System.out.printf("%X\n", Double.doubleToLongBits(n2));
System.out.printf("%X\n", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(n2));
```

output:

```
7FF8000000000000
7FF8000000000000
7FF8000000000000
7FF8000000000100
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `doubleToRawLongBits`!

Answer (score 7):

Java uses [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) for its floating point numbers and therefore follows their rules.

According to the [Wikipedia page on NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) it is defined like this:

> A bit-wise example of a IEEE floating-point standard single precision NaN: `x111 1111 1axx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx` where `x` means *don't care*.

So there are quite a few bit-patterns all of which are `NaN` values.

Comment: Thanks. Is this guaranteed to be portable across VMs?

Comment: @simonn: that question would make me stop for a moment: How exactly do you want to make use of that fact? Do you try to submit in-band information inside the NaN value of a `double`?

Comment: Sort of. I am trying to emulate the semantics of a system where there are several different values which all act like NaN, but they are distinguishable.

Comment: Just as a side-note: I've since learned that distinguishing different `NaN` values is **not portable** in Java. Some implementations may support it, others may collapse all `NaN` values to a small set of "legit" ones. That may happen at *any* time, *including* simple assignments.

Answer (score 3):

IEEE 754 defines a NaN as a number with all exponent bits which are `1` and a non zero number in the mantissa.

So for a single-precision number you are looking for:

```
S     E            M
x  11111111   xxxxxx....xxx (with M != 0)
```

Java handles this like so:

```
Double n = Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L); // default NaN
Double n2 = Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000100L); // also a NaN, but M != 0

System.out.println(n.isNaN()); // true
System.out.println(n2.isNaN()); // true
System.out.println(n2 != Double.doubleToLongBits(Double.NaN)); // true
```

To sum, you can use any NaN you want which conforms to the rules aforementioned (all bits 1 in exponent and mantissa != 0).

Comment: The last statement makes no sense.  `Double.doubleToLongBits(...)` is a `long`, which is implicitly converted to `double`, autoboxed and compared by *reference* to `n2`.

Comment: Possibly in the last line should be `Double.doubleToLongBits(n2) != Double.doubleToLongBits(Double.NaN)`  ?

Comment: That prints `false`, because `doubleToLongBits` converts all `NaN` s to the same value.  But it's true if you use `doubleToRawLongBits`.

Comment: I was wrong about the reference comparison (I just looked at the bytecode.)  The `long` is converted to `double`, but `n2` is auto-unboxed and normal `double` comparison is applied.