# How are NaN values represented in the simple Numpy file format?

Tags: java, numpy

I'm writing a program in a JVM language that stores an array of `Double[]` in the numpy simple file format, described [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/npy-format.rst). I then read these into an `ndarray` using

```py
np.readstring(str,dtype="float64")
```

Endianess aside, this works fine, as both Java and Numpy use the same IEEE standard for storing double values. It also appears to work with `int32` without problems. My question is, 1) how can I store `NaN` values in the Java side? 2) more generally, how are `NaN`s represented in the numpy simple file format linked above?

Comment: Did you try to write a ``new Double[] { Double.NaN }``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for java.lang.Double.NaN](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) says that it is

> A constant holding a Not-a-Number (NaN) value of type double. It is equivalent to the value returned by Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L).

(that part shamelessly scraped from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154484/what-are-the-other-nan-values) )

To answer your questions directly:

1. NaNs will store just like any other double on the Java side.
2. AS the spec you link to talks about encoding the values in raw binary form, I think you can put that value into the file like any other.

I think the real interesting question is - how will numpy interpret that value if it's loaded into numpy in python?

I *believe* the answer is that it will also interpret it as NaN as it conforms to the same IEEE spec for floating point numbers as Java.  However - I'd try a small test example to check it out first.

Comment: This appears to work for both floating point and integer numbers. Just have to remember that in Java tests need to be done with Int.isNaN or equivalent (instead of using (in)equality operators)