# Inconsistency in java.lang.Double implementation (Oracle JDK 1.8)?

Tags: java, java-8, double, jls

I looked at the implementation of the `java.lang.Double` class. The value of `NaN` is the specified value of `0x7ff8000000000000L`. The `public static final double NaN` field is set to `0.0d / 0.0` which should evaluate to `0x7ff8000000000000L` if the JVM does implement it that way.

1. Why was this value (`0x7ff8000000000000L`) chosen? Is there anything special about that value (e.g. its bit mask)?
2. Why is the field implicitly set to that value and depends on the underlying implementation of the `0.0d / 0.0` operation whereas the static method `public static long doubleToLongBits(double value)` sets the value explicitly to `0x7ff8000000000000L` for a `NaN` argument? Wasn't it much safer to implicitly set it as the result of `0.0d / 0.0` highly depends on the implementation of the JVM and could be changed (most likely it never will) theoretically?

The same goes for `POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. Fields are implicitly set to their values but some methods use the explicit specified values. Is there a reason behind that?

Thanks for helping me to learn anything new each day :-).

Comment: 1. That is the value specified in IEEE754.

Comment: `as the result of 0.0d / 0.0 highly depends on the implementation of the JVM and could be changed` - no, the JLS specifies that 0.d/0.0 returns NaN, so 0.d/0.0 is NaN by definition.

Comment: Relevant: [What are the other NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154484/what-are-the-other-nan-values)

Comment: @AndyTurner: That's _one of the values_ specified in IEEE754. But another would work just as well. In particular, NaN is not compared as other floats, as even the same value is not equal to itself: `Double.NaN == Double.NaN` is `false`. But all of them will return `true` for `Double.isNaN`.

Comment: Thanks so far :-). Still, why defining the value as a field and not reusing it in the class itself -> minimizing redundancy? And I do understand that the value was chosen randomly and does not have a "deeper meaning" to it?

Comment: Surely the fact that `0x7ff8000000000000L` is a long precludes its use in specifying a double-valued field.

Comment: @Andy Turner Ok sure, I totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The `public static final double NaN` field is set to `0.0d / 0.0` which should evaluate to `0x7ff8000000000000L` if the JVM does implement it that way.

No: it results in `NaN`, per [the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2):

> Division of a zero by a zero results in NaN

`0x7ff8000000000000L` is a `long`, not a `double`, hence that cannot be used as the field initializer directly.

[The documentation of `Double.NaN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) does state that its value "is equivalent to the value returned by `Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L)`." However, `0.0d / 0.0` is used in preference to that to initialize the field because it is a compile-time constant value, whereas method invocations are not.

(Shameless plug for [my answer about why it is `0.0d`, not `0.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41283474/3788176))

---

> Why was this value (`0x7ff8000000000000L`) chosen?

As noted in [JLS Sec 4.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3):

> IEEE 754 allows multiple distinct NaN values for each of its single and double floating-point formats. While each hardware architecture returns a particular bit pattern for NaN when a new NaN is generated, a programmer can also create NaNs with different bit patterns to encode, for example, retrospective diagnostic information.
>
> For the most part, the Java SE Platform treats NaN values of a given type as though collapsed into a single canonical value, and hence this specification normally refers to an arbitrary NaN as though to a canonical value.

The `Double.longBitsToDouble` method has to return *a* value, so this is the value they chose to return.

Comment: AFAICS The NaN chosen is the smallest value as a long.